# Heat and Wave equation - Green's function versus Fourier series?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, heat-equation, wave-equation

I am learning how to solve the heat and wave equation in bounded domains in 1 and 2D as well as in $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$. In the latter case I have learned the representation formulas i.e. heat kernel/Green's function and d'Alembert's formula. I do not understand why the bounded domain case (where I am using Fourier series and separation of variables) is so different from the solutions in the whole space. I have tried solving the heat equation on $\Omega=[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ for $a<b$ and taking the limit as $a\rightarrow -\infty$ and $b\rightarrow \infty$ but I am not getting anywhere. Can someone explain to me why we need to different methodologies for bounded domain case and the whole space for both the heat and wave equation?

Comment: yes obtaining the Fourier transform from the Fourier series by letting $|b-a| \to \infty$ is not so easy in the general case. do you know the Fourier transform ? and the distributions ?

Comment: I have learned about the Fourier transform and the Schwartz space - but I was hoping to see the interplay between the series and the representation formula first since the distributional interpretation of the PDEs is still a bit challenging for me to follow. Is that what you were thinking of?